# A type of combination without repetitions and multiple sets of variable length

Tags: combinations

I don't know what this is called (though I know it falls under combinations) but I have a problem where I start with multiple groups of variable size.

Given:
There are N groups
Each group has at least one member

Ex:

```
Group 1: A, B, C
Group 2: D, E, F, X
Group 3: Y, Z
```

The problem is such:

How many unique groups of 2 can be created given that you cannot choose two members from the same group?
(A, D) is a valid group of 2, but (A, B) is not because both are in the same group.

I know the formula for combinations is `n!/( r! (n-r)!)`, but I'm unsure how to adjust this for multiple groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $n_i$ members of the $i$th group with $i$ running from $1$ through to $N$, then the number of was of choosing one from group $i$ and one from group $j$ is simply $n_i n_j$ so the total number of possibilities is $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N n_i n_j.$$

If $N$ is large you might find it easier to calculate $$\dfrac{\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i\right)^2 -\sum_{i=1}^{N}  \left(n_i^2\right)}{2} .$$

In your example this would be $3\times 4 + 3\times 2 +4 \times 2$ or $\dfrac{(3+4+2)^2 - (3^2+4^2+2^2)}{2} .$

Comment: Thank you, still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I had to write out a few examples to understand the formula, it works, thanks.